# video File conversion from any fromat to webm in windows using ffmpeg command line

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

I need to convert a video from any format which is uploaded to WebM. I am using video tag to play videos in browsers the code which I am using works fine for mp4 conversion but it doesn't for the WebM format file. so please find me a solution

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -y  -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 800k -f webm -s 514*362 OUTPUT_FILE.WEBM
```

Comment: See if this works [link] (http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/)

Comment: ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -vf showinfo -strict -2 OUTPUT_FILE.WEBM , i tried this command in prompt but it says unrecognized option -vf pls help me

Comment: i am trying to convert any video format to webm using the above code so that i can play converted video in html5 using different browsers but conversation itself doesn't happen..

Comment: I don't see why you just don't play the video file in the format that it is in, since all browsers should be able to handle it.

Comment: Doesn't play the converted files with jplayer, please get me working code that would be more satisfactory ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to explicitly mention the video codec with -c:v && the audio codec with -c:a (and I am not sure why you used * instead of x in the -s tag)

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -y -c:v libvpx -g 52 -b:v 800k -f webm -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -s 514x362 OUTPUT_FILE.webm
```

Comment: Hi is there command which'll convert any uploaded file to mp4 foramt using ffmpeg

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i  INPUT_FILE -f mp4 -c:a libfaac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264  -vprofile baseline -movflags faststart OUTPUT_FILE.mp4

Comment: Thank u,i 've downloaded the new http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ from this link and tried to execute your command but i got error like : Unknown encoder 'libfaac' so to resolve this error i downloaded the libfacc.dll but still it's the same error pls help me out to solve this errror